# How to rbind all the data.frames in your working environment?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have over 50 data.frames in my working environment that I would like to *rbind*. Is there a way to *rbind* the *data.frames* with out having to type out each *date.frame*?

Example of what I have been doing:

```
df <- rbind(A, B, C, D, E, F)
```

I have tried:

```
df <- rbind(ls())
```

But this just creates a list of names of all the data.frames in my working environment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can search for objects of `data.frame` class, and use function `mget` to retrieve them.

```
a = b = c = data.frame(x=1:2, y=3, z=1:4)
d = "junk"
e = list(poo="pah")
ls()
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
dfs = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame) 
dfs
#    a     b     c     d     e 
# TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
do.call(rbind, mget(names(dfs)[dfs]))
#     x y z
# a.1 1 3 1
# a.2 2 3 2
# a.3 1 3 3
# a.4 2 3 4
# b.1 1 3 1
# b.2 2 3 2
# b.3 1 3 3
# b.4 2 3 4
# c.1 1 3 1
# c.2 2 3 2
# c.3 1 3 3
# c.4 2 3 4
```

Comment: I'm with you up until the last `do.call` part then I get an error message `Error: value for ‘x1’ not found`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidPell ; apologies, I have not been on site. Its hard to say what's happeneing. Are you able to create an example, similar to what I did in the answer, that shows your problem.