# R: Remove a row from all data.frames in global environment

Tags: r, dataframe

I have over 200 data.frames in my global environment. I would like to remove the first row from each data.frame, but I am not sure how.

Any help will be appreciated please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: How did you wind up with such a mess? It would probably be better to keep those data.frames in a list rather than polluting your global environment like that. They would be much easier to work with that way.

Comment: See [How to make a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) to follow-up on MrFlick's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will list all the data frames in your environment, remove the first row from each, and organize them into a list of data frames. Generally, better practice to have them in a list so you can more easily `apply` functions across them and access them.

`df <- lapply(ls(), function(x) get(x)[-1,])`

Update: good idea to check if objects are in fact data frames and only work with those. First we create a logical vector listing dataframes, then combine them into a list and remove the first row of each.

```
dfs = sapply(ls(), is.data.frame) 
lapply(mget(names(dfs)[dfs]), "[", -1, , drop = FALSE)
```

thanks to comments for finding my error and providing more efficient solutions

Comment: you should probably add a check that the object is a dataframe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387419/how-to-rbind-all-the-data-frames-in-your-working-environment-in-r/35387595#35387595